# What are some Encryption functions with Poor Confusion

Tags: encryption

I've recently been learning about Confusion and diffusion related to encryption functions. For the most part I get the gist of what they are but I was wondering if there are any functions with Poor confusion

Comment: Welcome to [cryptography.se]. Ideally, we don't design in that manner. If such poor confusion exists, it is a direct attack point to Linear and Differential attack. Weak SBox is the key to poor confusion. Even DES's Sboxes were not weak. Note that even with a simple round function we can have a secure cipher after many rounds, see Tiny Encryption Algorithm. If you are looking for some historical ciphers see permutation cipher.

Comment: FEAL was a proposed alternative to DES, and had *very* poor confusion (enough that breaking it is a common exercise in cryptanalysis courses).